# std::initializer_list as constructor argument in template class

Tags: c++, templates, stdinitializerlist

I'm trying to use std::initializer_list in a constructor to accept variable number of arguments. With non-template class it works fine, but with template class it gives compiling errors. Could anyone possiblly point me to the right direction? My g++ is capable of C++17.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <initializer_list>

struct Nontemplate
{
    // std::initializer_list for a function taking variable number of arguments
    template <class Iterator>
    Nontemplate(std::initializer_list<Iterator> list) {
        std::cout << "size: " << list.size() << std::endl;
        for(auto it : list) {
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

template <class T, class TIterator>
struct Template
{
    std::vector<T> vec;

    Template(std::initializer_list<TIterator> list)
    {
        if(!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type, T>::value)
            throw std::runtime_error("Iterator value type is not the expected.");

        std::cout << "size: " << list.size() << std::endl;

        vec.clear();
        vec.reserve(list.size());
        for(T val : list)
            vec.push_back(val);
    }
};

int main()
{
    double vec[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};

    Nontemplate cls0({vec, vec+2, vec+3, vec+4}); // no problem
    //Template cls1({vec, vec+2, vec+3, vec+4});  // compiling error
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the compilation errors you're getting?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: The error message is: main.cpp:42:45: error: class template argument deduction failed:
   42 |     Template cls1({vec, vec+2, vec+3, vec+4});  // compiling error

Comment: From `Template cls1({vec, vec+2, vec+3, vec+4});`, there's no way to deduce `T`, only `TIterator`

Comment: You need to pass Template Argumnets in Template<?,?> cls1....

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik That's true.

Comment: `Template<double> cls1({vec, vec+2, vec+3, vec+4});` Or `Template<double, double*>` if you want to specify both parameters explicitly

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Your first one give an error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Your second one works - if I change "for(T val : list)" to "for(T* val : list)". Thanks.

Comment: Elements of `list` are of type `TIterator`, not `T`. `TIterator` may or may not be the same as `T*`

Comment: That's correct. In my real project, I use "auto" instead of T*. Thanks.

Comment: @jianz `Template<double, double*>` should fix your compiler error, but there's no template argument deduction here. You could just have one template parameter: `TIterator` and base your vector on that: `std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type> vec;` Then you don't have to supply the types yourself to the template. Plus it becomes a compile time check.

Comment: @ jignatius Thanks for the great solution. Your solution is the same of the third method in Jarod42's answer, which I have accepted as the solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Template cls1({vec, vec+2, vec+3, vec+4})` has no ways to deduce T.

You might use

`Template<double, double*> cls1({vec, vec+2, vec+3, vec+4});`

or provide custom deduction guide:

```
template <typename It>
Template(std::initializer_list<It>)
-> Template<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type, It>;
```

Or simplify your class to remove that `T`

```
template <class TIterator>
struct Template
{
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type;
    std::vector<T> vec;

    Template(std::initializer_list<TIterator> list)
    {
        std::cout << "size: " << list.size() << std::endl;

        vec.clear();
        vec.reserve(list.size());
        for(T val : list)
            vec.push_back(val);
    }
};
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Before your post, I have been using the "Template<double, double*>" method. What I was looking for are the other two alternatives you provided here. Thanks a lot. Could you possible correct typos - I have already accepted this as the solution. 1) custom deduction guide method: "-> Template<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type, It>;" 2) Removing T method: "using T = typename std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type;"

Comment: @jianz: typos fixed. (feel free to edit if it remains some).